# Is the ring $\frac{\Bbb{C}[X,Y,Z]}{(XY-Z)}$ a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I think the ring $\frac{\Bbb{C}[X,Y,Z]}{(XY-Z)}$ is a UFD.

If we consider the evaluation map $f: \Bbb{C}[X,Y,Z] \rightarrow \Bbb{C}[t^2,t]$ such $f(X)=f(Y)=t$ and $f(Z)=t^2$. Then clearly $(Z-XY)$ is in $\ker f$. Now suppose $p \in \ker f$. Then considering $p$ as a polynomial is $\Bbb{C}[X,Y][Z]$, we have by division algorithm $p=q(Z-XY)+r$, where $q,r \in \Bbb{C}[X,Y][Z] $. If $r \neq 0$, then $\deg r < 1$ in $\Bbb{C}[X,Y][Z]$. So $r \in \Bbb{C}[X,Y]$. Also $f(r)=0$. Now if $r= \displaystyle{\sum_{m,n}c_{(m,n)}X^mY^n}$, then $f(r)=0 \Rightarrow r(t,t)=0 \Rightarrow \displaystyle{\sum_{m,n}c_{(m,n)}t^{m+n}}=0 \Rightarrow c_{(m,n)}=0 \,\forall \, m,n$. So $r=0$. Hence we have $\frac{\Bbb{C}[X,Y,Z]}{(XY-Z)}\approx \Bbb{C}[t^2,t]$.

Now is $\Bbb{C}[t^2,t]$ a UFD?

If so then we are done !

Comment: Your $f$ is not an isomorphism, because $Y$ and $X$ are not in the same coset of $(XY-Z)$. Instead, can you produce an isomorphism between $\Bbb{C}[X,Y,Z]/(XY-Z)$ and $\Bbb{C}[X,Y]$?

Comment: Your conclusion that all $c_{m,n}=0$ is false since different $m$ and $n$ lead to the same $t^{m+n}$. For example $X-Y$ is in the kernel of your map (in fact, the kernel is $(X-Y,Z-XY)$). Also note that $\mathbb C[t^2,t]$ is just a strange notation for $\mathbb C[t]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel of your proposed map $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]\to\mathbb C[t]$ with $X, Y\mapsto t$ and $Z\mapsto t^2$ is not $(Z-XY)$ but $(Z-XY,X-Y)$. However, note that dividing by $(Z-XY)$ just imposes the relation $\overline Z=\overline X\,\overline Y$ in the quotient, which effectively let's us get rid of $Z$:

Consider the ring homomorphism $g\colon \mathbb C[X,Y,Z]\to\mathbb C[X,Y]$ given by $X\mapsto X$, $Y\mapsto Y$ and $Z\mapsto XY$. This is a surjective ring homomorphism with kernel $(Z-XY)$ and hence
$$
\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/(Z-XY) \cong \mathbb C[X,Y].
$$

For any UFD $R$, the polynomial ring $R[X]$ is a UFD as well. Since $\mathbb C$ is a UFD, so is $\mathbb C[X]$ and hence $\mathbb C[X,Y]\cong \mathbb C[X][Y]$ is a UFD as well.

Comment: Okay I get it. Thank you so much.